What is the role of @Transactional(readOnly = true) in Spring MongoDB
I understand that when using transactions in MongoDB with the WiredTiger storage engine, the isolation level is fixed to snapshot.
If I use @Transactional(readOnly = true), it allows consistent reads based on the snapshot created at the beginning of the transaction. On the other hand, if I don't use @Transactional(readOnly = true), the read consistency is provided according to the readConcern. Is my understanding correct?
Additionally, I am curious whether developers who use Spring MongoDB typically use @Transactional(readOnly = true) when performing read-only operations. I would also like to know if using @Transactional(readOnly = true) impacts performance.

Have some benefits. When using the (readonly=true) option, hibernate's session flush mode is set to MANUAL, so Hibernate not manage that data in persistence context and not occur dirty check and snapshot and not set transaction id.
And if using master db and other some slave db in DB Replication, use that option can reduce the load on master db by calling select with slave db.

Hibernate ORM is a Domain model persistence for relational databases. The question is related to MongoDB, a non-relational (a NoSQL, document) database. You cannot use Hibernate directly without the Hibernate Object/Grid Mapper (OGM). As of today the Hibernate website shows this message: "Hibernate OGM is not maintained anymore".
